# Creating n tier application

Tags: design-patterns, n-tier-architecture

I am new to design patterns. I want to learn constructing 3 tier architecture. I have searched but confused at some points. In this article http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/show/18/4-tier-architecture-in-aspnet-with-csharp writer adds another tier named Business Object tier. According to me it is very useful to transfer data from one tier to another. And since this tier only includes business objects we can add reference of this tier to others and this does not break rules.

But some other articles, they are using DTOs. With this approach we have to convert data between DAL and BAL.

I think using Business object layer is more logical and easy and I cannot see any disadvantages of using it.

Please help me to come to a stable solution. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Because you are using the business objects globally, throughout the entire application, having their own tier would work. Because the business objects are not implementation-specific, they should't be tightly coupling you to any external dependencies. That is assuming you aren't using a data access technology such as Linq to Sql, where Sql specific code would be needed on the objects.

In the last couple years, though, I have moved towards the 'onion-architecture' design. I keep my business objects (entities) and my interfaces in a core projects. I add all my business code and implementation-specific code to a services project, and finally the standard UI project. The UI and services project each are only aware of the core. All my services implement one of the interfaces in the core, and my UI code is written against core interfaces rather than concrete implementations of services. In this way, my UI and my services are completely decoupled and have no knowledge of one another. This pattern can also be expanded to include other projects (i use infrastructure for cross-cutting concerns such as logging).

For the n-tier approach, though, I think the business object tier is fine. You could also return some sort of native data record (DataTable, etc in C#) to your business layer, keep your objects there, and include a constructor that accepts the native data type.

Answer (score 1):

The separate physical location of these tiers is what differentiates n-tier architecture from the model-view-controller framework that only separates presentation, logic, and data tiers in concept.